# Are equivalence relations total, i.e. are all elements of an equivalence relation related one to each other?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

**Some definitions** that I am aware of:

> 1. **Equivalence relation:** Is reflexive, symmetric and transitive
> 2. **Equivalence class of $a$ under equivalence relation $R$ $[a]_R$:** set of all elements that are related to an element a
> 3. **Partition and Equivalence class:**
>
>    - A partition of a set S is a collection of disjoint nonempty subsets of S that have S as their union.
>    - Thus, equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on a set form a partition of the set.
> 4. **POSET / Partial Ordering:** Is antisymmetric, reflexive, transitive relation.
> 5. **TOSET / Totally ordered POSET:** POSET with every two elements in the set are comparable

**The question**

> Suppose $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $π_1$ is the following partition of A
>   $π_1=\{\{a,b,c\}\{d\}\}$. List the ordered pairs of the equivalence relations induced by $π_1$.

**The answer given**

> $\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c),(d,d)\}$

**My doubt**
Equivalence relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.
But that does not means that all symmetric and transitive pairs should be there in the equivalence class, right? We can just have reflexive pairs also, right? Like this: $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)\}$, right? Now someone will say, for pairs $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)\}$, equivalence classes will be $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\}\}$. But I feel that's not compulsory, right? Have a look at definition of partition / equivalence relation again:

> A partition of a set S is a collection of disjoint nonempty subsets (which are equivalence relation) of S that have S as their union.

Thus given equivalence relation, we can combine two or more (say $A$ and $B$) of them to form bigger equivalence relation. In that equivalence relation also, symmetricity, reflexivity and transitivity will follow. But there might not be pairs such as $aRb$ and $bRa$. Thus its not equivalence class, even though equivalence relation hold on it and it still forms part of valid partition (union of them forms whole set and they are disjoint). In other words,

> **(1)** Partition is made of sets, which may or may not be equivalence classes (as partitions have only requirement that they are disjoint and their union form an original set).
>   **(2)** Set of equivalence classes on a set form a partition.

So if all above thoughts are right and since question does not use word "equivalence ***class***", but "equivalence ***relation***", am I right with the fact that we can just have reflexive pairs (or even some symmetric and transitive pairs, if not all), for example $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d),(a,b),(b,a)\}$. Here,

- $(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)$ are what I call as reflexive pairs, i.e. pairs which confirm that the relation is reflexive
- $(a,b),(b,a)$ are what I call as symmetric pairs, i.e. pairs which confirm that the relation is symmetric
- in this example, there is no pair (x,y) dictated by transitive relationship

Comment: There is always one and only one total equivalence relation in each set: for a set $A$, that's $A^2$. I don't see what you mean with combining equivalence relations. If it is the union, then in general it's not an equivalence relation, but there is an equivalence relation generated by the union. It's not very clear what is your question, after all...

Comment: what's a transitive pair ?

Comment: @amrsa I know equivalence relations are not closed under union, because union may not be transitive. This will happen when there is common element in two relations. For example, consider equivalence relations $\{(a,b),(b,a)\}$ and $\{(b,c),(c,b)\}$. Here, $b$ is common in both. So union will not contain $(a,c)$ (as dictated by $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$). However this will not happen in case of taking union of partition's equivalence relations as they are disjoint. Right?

Comment: @mercio by transitive pairs, I meant pairs obtained by considering transitive  relationship. For example, can ordered pairs be $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d),(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b),(a,c)\}$. Here $(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)$ are reflexive pairs. $(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b)$ are symmetric pairs and $(a,c)$ is transitive pair obtained from $(a,b),(b,c)$.

Comment: Yes, the union of two equivalence relations $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is an equivalence relation if each block of $\alpha$ is contained in a block of $\beta$ or is a union of blocks of $\beta$.

Comment: @amrsa Sorry I made mistake [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643472/are-equivalence-relations-total-i-e-are-all-elements-of-an-equivalence-relatio#comment5459950_2643472) it should be "as dictated by $(a,b)$ and $(b,\color{red}{c})$"

Comment: I don't think it is correct to call reflexive, symmetric or transitive to pairs of the equivalence relation. It is also confusing and it doesn't seem correct english (or other language). Sometimes, the pairs $(a,a)$ are called pairs from the diagonal; pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ called converse (or reverse?) of each other; to those which result from the transitive closure I never have heard called them anything special.

Comment: Yeah I just used those terms first time, felt that it will conveniently make sense about what I was trying to tell. Are those terms that confusing? What else we can call them? Also is question clear now?

Comment: For example, in your question following "My doubt", what do you mean by all symmetric and transitive pairs? That is meaningless. It is true that those pairs which you call reflexive are enough, but the relation $\{(a,a):a \in A\}$ is symmetric and transitive just the same; hence it is an equivalence relation. So what would the symmetric/transitive pairs be in this case? Can you see that it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Another thing: in the answer given you missed the commas separating the pairs, and the same above in the definition of $\pi_1$, you should have separated the blocks with a comma too.

Comment: In reply to [necessity of symmetric and transitive pair comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643472/are-equivalence-relations-total-i-e-are-all-elements-of-an-equivalence-relatio#comment5460032_2643472), yes I understand $\{(a,a):a\in A\}$ is symmetric and transitive. Thats why in question, I have deliberately used words "(***or even some*** symmetric and transitive pairs, ***if not all***)". That means none, some or all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72940/discussion-between-amrsa-and-anir).

Comment: One more thing: remove the 'order-theory' and 'lattice-orders' tags from this question. These are not relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be overlooking the last three words of the question. The question doesn't want any old equivalence relation on $A$ you can come up with -- it want the *particular* equivalence relation **"induced by $\pi_1$**".

Perhaps you have missed that "the equivalence relation that such-and-such partition induces" has a particular definition? The exercise is asking you to apply that definition to find which one of the many possible equivalence relations on $A$ it is speaking about.

There are various equivalent ways to define this concept -- we can either say

> We say that the equivalence relation $R$ is **induced by** the partition $\pi$ if the elements of $\pi$ are exactly the equivalence classes under $R$.

or

> Given a partition $\pi$, the equivalence relation **induced by** this partition is the relation $R_\pi$ defined by $$ x\mathrel{R_\pi}y \iff \exists P\in\pi: \{x,y\}\subseteq P $$

Comment: One precise question which sums up all my doubts. In the book by Kenneth Rosen, there is a sentence: "a partition of a set S is a collection of disjoint nonempty subsets of S that have S as their union.". Though the author have equivalence relation and classes discussed on the same page, he wrote above sentence, which does not say partitioning sets should always be equivalence classes. So, I felt any disjoint nonempty partitions with their union = S will do, regardless of whether symmetry, reflexivity and transitivity hold on them. Reading your answer, I feel that is not correct, right?

Comment: @anir: symmetry, reflexivity, transitivity are not properties of the parts in the partition.  It just doesn't make any sense to ask if those properties hold there.  Those are properties of *relations*.  If the relation is one **induced by** (not identical to) the partition, then yes, those properties must hold.

Comment: @anir: The point is that whenever you have a partition, no matter where you get it from, there is automatically _one particular equivalence relation_ whose equivalence classes _are_ exactly the sets in the partition. The exercise is to construct _that_ equivalence relation for the partition you're given.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given is correct.  You are right that the relation
$$
    \{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)\}
$$
is also an equivalence relation—it's a *different* equivalence relation.  And it yields a different partition.

Comment: The question is if the given answer is the only answer for the given question. Because that is what is stated in the book. Is my answer too valid.

Comment: @anir: no, your answer is wrong.  Equivalence relations and partitions are in one-to-one correspondence.  So if two equivalence relations give different partitions, they are different equivalence relations.